# Linking CPR C++ library with OMNET++

Tags: c++, eclipse, omnet++

I have succesfully installed OMNET++ and now I want to link OMNET with a REST API library called CPR. Usually, in Eclipse (Which OMNET++ is based on) I would do the linking something like *project properties->C/C++ build->Settings->GCC C++ Linker->Libraries->[-l section]*. Now in OMNET I have tried linking it by going to *Project -> Properties -> Makemake -> Options -> Additional Libraries to link with (-l option)* and include: **cpr**.

But it returns an error:

> ld.lld error: unable to find library -lcpr

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cpr` library should be on your library path (i.e. usually on /usr/lib). Otherwise you must specify also the `-L` option to specify the directory where that given library is.

Comment: You're right, the library was not in /usr/lib but in /usr/local/lib. I included that option into the OMNET++ configuration *Include directories, relative to this makefile(-I)*. It is an uppercase I. According with the preview of the compiler, the full code to be executed is *-f -deep -I/usr/local/lib -lcpr*. But there is an error saying: ld.lld error unable to find library -lcpr

Comment: No, you MUST specify the LIBRARY directory, not the include directory. So you have to add -L for the library dir (and not -I)

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I didn't find the option to include the library path (the -L option) in OMNET++. If you could tell me where to find that it would be much appreciated.

Comment: In *Project properties / C/C++ General / Path and Symbols / Library Paths*, however it's  much better to create a `makefrag` file and add `LIBS += -L/path/lib/dir -lcpr` there as this would affect both the command line and the IDE build, and it's much more visible for the user (and easier to check in to repositories etc.)

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. But now if I do it like that, (Both options, the library paths and the makefrag file) it compiles correctly, but when I'm going to run the program an error  jumps : 
<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../../../src//libsimu5g.so': ../../../../src//libsimu5g.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3cpr7SessionC1Ev

Which doesn't make any sense, as that library is working. The error is only shown when I try to use some of the CPR library classes or methods

Comment: This clearly shows that the cpr library is NOT linked to simu5g i.e. -lcpr is definitely not on the linker command line.

Comment: Hello @Rudi, me again. I updated to Ubuntu 22.04 and everything stopped working, so I had to re-install Ubuntu 20 from scratch. I thought that it would be better to do it properly this time. I understand now that I have to link the library through a 'makefrag', but could you explain me how to do that exactly ? thanks in advance for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone else is wondering this. I just copied the library dependencies (The .so, .zlib-ng and .1 files) into my `usr/lib` directory. After that, I included the library through `

> Project properties -> Omnet++ -> Makemake -> Makemake Options -> link

` and include "**cpr**" in the *-l option*. And now it's working.

Probably not the best answer but it works for me.

Comment: I would have left the libraries in /usr/local/lib and did what the other answer told you to do. Use the `-L` option to specify the additional library folder